# How to enable/disable auto connect flag in android wifi saved network

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am adding the network in the WifiManager but it gives me the option to set name and SSID only. I want to enable/disable the auto-connect flag based on some conditions. Is there any way to do that?